# How to expose Web Socket in Node-RED?

Tags: http, websocket, get, node-red

We are working on project where our goal is to display real time sensor data through browser. We have real **AM2302 temperature sensor** running on Raspberry Pi. The temperature sensor publish data and node in **Node-RED** subscribe for the data that is published by Temperature Sensor on Raspberry Pi. Now, after receiving data in Node-RED, we would like to **expose that data** using **websocket** (output node). Now we connect **http**(input node using **GET** method) to previously created websocket(output node) to receive data value and we display using debug node. But problem is, it doesn't display any data to debug console and also doesn't display any error. What should we do ? Are we missing something ?
Code for nodes of Node-RED is shown below (in json format).

```
[{"id":"e9e5dd7a.161a2","type":"websocket- 
listener","z":"","path":"/ws/temperatureValue","wholemsg":"false"},
{"id":"5b8e213a.a471e","type":"mqtt-
 broker","z":"98791dce.6786e","broker":"test.mosquitto.org","port":"1883","client
 id":"","usetls":false,"verifyservercert":true,"compatmode":true,"keepalive":"15"
,"cleansession":true,"willTopic":"","willQos":"0","willRetain":"false","willPayl
 oad":"","birthTopic":"","birthQos":"0","birthRetain":"false","birthPayload":""},
 {"id":"61aceb43.9e5314","type":"debug","z":"98791dce.6786e","name":"","active":t
rue,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":712,"y":280,"wires":[]},
{"id":"b3cf17f1.4c30e8","type":"mqtt         
in","z":"98791dce.6786e","name":"Temperature Sensor 
    Publisher","topic":"sensorMeasurement","broker":"5b8e213a.a471e","x":215,"y":245
,"wires":[["f81d74ae.07e288"]]},{"id":"f81d74ae.07e288","type":"websocket 
 out","z":"98791dce.6786e","name":"","server":"e9e5dd7a.161a2","client":"","x":47
2,"y":193,"wires":[]},{"id":"d2181548.2de7e8","type":"http 
in","z":"98791dce.6786e","name":"","url":"/temperatureValue","method":"get","swa
ggerDoc":"","x":432,"y":321,"wires":[["61aceb43.9e5314"]]}]
```

Comment: The http-in "GET" is totally unrelated to the Websocket connection, there will be no interaction between them. Any MQTT message payload that arrives will be forward to any Websocket client that arrives with what you have.

Comment: @hardillb. Many thanks for correcting me!!! I am bit new to websocket. Could you please advise  -- how can I get data exposed through web socket on my client ??

Comment: The data is already exposed via Websockets, you will need to write the web client side code to connect to it and process the data, but that has nothing to do with Node-RED